# Summarise with grouped variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that consists of 3 different columns (a,b and noise).
I want to apply a function on all **distinct** combinations of the two first columns together with the mean of the third variable and save it in a new column named c.
My first thought was to solve it with the following code

```
library(dplyr)

df  <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1,2,3),each=9),
                   b = rep(c(1,2,3),length.out=3*9),
                   noise = rnorm(9*3*1000))

f <- function(a,b,c) a + b + c


result <- df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(c = f(a,b,mean(noise)))
```

To my surprise this gave the error "Error: expecting a single value".
So dlyr still treats a and b as vectors.
So the problem could then be solved with the somewhat confusing code

```
result <- df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(c = f(a[1],b[1],mean(noise)))
```

My questions are:

- Why do dplyr keep grouped variables as vectors (are there any benefits of this?)
- Is there any better way to solve this problem using dplyr?

Comment: I didn't see your update.  Looks like you already solved the problem.  A possible modification would be `df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(C= f(first(a), first(b), mean(noise)))` or `df %>% group_by(a,b) %>% summarise(C= mean(noise)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(C= Reduce('+', .))`

Comment: I solved the problem already before posting the question I just thought that it was strange that you had to index the grouped variables and wondered why?

Comment: Because `summarise` returns only a single row per grouping variable.  So, without using the index, it is actually doing the `sum` for each of the elements in each group with the `mean` of the noise which is a `mutate` step.

Comment: Yes I understand that the first piece of code will try to add a vector of length 3000 (a value) and a vector of 3000 (b value) and the the mean of the noise variable (a vector of length 1) which will result in a vector of length 3000 and thus the error. The question is why would dplyr have this behavior and doesn't see that the variable is used for grouping and use it as a number instead or are there any special symbols to refer to the value of a grouped variable?

Comment: IMO, it's not so much about dplyr but about the way `+` works

Comment: Well it's not only how + behaves. In the first piece of code f will be applied to two vectors of length 3000 and one of length 1. Different function just handles it differently (+,-,*...)  returns a vector of length 3000. If f is min the minumum of a b and the mean noise will be returned (the first piece of code will accually work)

Comment: Right, you are just confirming what I said. If you applied a different function, for example `min`, it would work, _because `min` always returns a length-1-vector_ while `+` returns a vector of the same length as its input. From `help("+")`: `The binary operators return vectors containing the result of the element by element operations. If involving a zero-length vector the result has length zero. Otherwise, the elements of shorter vectors are recycled as necessary (with a warning when they are recycled only fractionally).`